# C# IO Exception

Tags: c#, exception, io

Im trying to save a file that i download from a mailbox. This hasnt been any problems, but now that i'v built a GUI upon my modell i get and Authorization exception:

```
Saved file: C:\TempNorlander
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\TempNorlander' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at a.a0.b(String A_0, Byte[] A_1, Int32 A_2, Int32 A_3)
   at MailBee.Mime.Attachment.Save(String filename, Boolean overwrite)
   at Mail2DB.Connect2Exchange.CollectData() in C:\Users\marthin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Mail2DB\Mail2DB\Connect2Exchange.cs:line 210
```

I cant figure out what the problem is here. In the folder iv set all possible users have all priviliges.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that now with the GUI i enter the folderpath in a simple textBox. (via a FolderBrowserDialog)

SECOND EDIT:

Im Runnig this on a windows 7 and VS 2010.
Thx for any help!
/Marthin

Comment: Its a Windows Application, users fill in there connection info to a exchange server and the mail with some and csv files are downloaded and parsed in to a DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Saved file: C:\TempNorlander

You are trying to save a file that has the same name as the folder.  That's not allowed, UnauthorizedAccessException is the result.  Fix the file name to, say, C:\TempNorlander\mumble.txt

Comment: Your correct, for some reason my path was incorrect. I used a 3:dpart lib for handling all paths and savings. Should read the manuell better i guess. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear:

> Access to the path 'C:\TempNorlander' is denied.

The user running this process doesn't have the right permissions to access this folder.

Either give this user the right permissions, or start the program using a user that has them already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a web project - by default your project will be run under the IIS `DefaultAppPool` which does not have rights to read an arbitrary file on your HD. You can fix this by

1. specifically allow the AppPool
   access to the folder/file by adding
   the rights in Explorer
2. use [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to read the file
   under the credentials of a different
   user
3. use a different identity for your
   application in IIS by creating
   another application pool or [changing the identity](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) of the existing one.

If your GUI is not a web project point 2 still applies- you need to impersonate a user that has read rights on the folder/file or add these rights to the user that your application is running under.

Comment: This is a Windows Application.

Answer (score 0):

Likely causes:

1. You can't really create a file in C: (which, by the way, you shouldn't)
2. You already have that file open in either another process or in your app
3. You are trying to overwrite an existing file and can't

Maybe you'd like to address the task you're really trying to accomplish.
For example, save some data into a temp file that can be accessed in the same session.  Or append to a persistent data file for an ASP.NET app that can be accessed in a later invocation.

For example, if this is a desktop application and you need to create a temporary file for saving data, you'd want to use [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) for that.